# How to insert one form in front of another (i.e. add a confirmation BEFORE a node add form)

Tags: forms

I am not exactly sure how to go about this with a form_alter hook.  What I want to do is insert a form prior to displaying the node add form.  This way, I can display a confirmation message prior to the node creation form.  I understand I can create a control key in the `$form_state` variable to keep track of where we are in a multi-step form, but how can I augment a non-multi-step default form (such as the node add form) to add in stages in front of it?  Would I have to override all the node add submit and validate callbacks as well?  Seems like a lot of effort to add a simple confirmation.